# Prompting user to input data info through multiple classes

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, prompt

I'm trying to create a Data Base program by using OOP. I've tried solving this several months, and can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. Went through examples and even a Udemy course, but circles back to what I know to the limit.

My objective is to allow the user input data and have it stored safely under another class. When the program ends, it'll output the user info from the other class vs. all in one class.

I've reviewed Udemy courses such as C# Master and look up on C# tutorials from Microsoft.

Code sheet 1

```
using System;

namespace DataBase
{
    public class Data
    {
        static string userFirst, userLast, userGender;
        static int userAge;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Data_Storage user = new Data_Storage(userFirst, userLast, userGender, userAge);

            Console.WriteLine("Please input First Name: ");
            userFirst = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please input Last Name: ");
            userLast = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please input Gender: ");
            userGender = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please input Age: ");
            userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        }
```

Code sheet 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DataBase
{
    class Data_Storage
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }

        //Implicitly
        public Data_Storage()
        {
            firstName = "First";
            lastName = "Last";
            gender = "Null";
            age = 0;
        }

        //Instance constructor
        public Data_Storage(string userFirst, string userLast, string userGender, int userAge)
        {
            this.firstName = userFirst;
            this.lastName = userLast;
            this.gender = userGender;
            this.age = userAge;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format(this.firstName + "\n" + this.lastName + "\n" + this.gender + "\n" + this.age);
        }

    }
}
```

When testing this code, it'll only return the default constructor I made instead of referencing my instance constructor.

Comment: It looks like you're creating an instance of the `Data_Storage` class *before* you have any values set in the variables you're passing to the constructor. You should create the instance *after* the user has entered the values.

Comment: You're creating `user` instance with variables before getting input into variables.

Comment: You really need to learn [how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
userFirst = Console.ReadLine();
```

Do this:

```
user.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

and repeat this for all of your other properties.  This will solve your problem.  You can also remove your whole constructor, so instead of this:

```
Data_Storage user = new Data_Storage(userFirst, userLast, userGender, userAge);
```

Do this:

```
var user = new Data_Storage();
```

You can also remove this:

```
static string userFirst, userLast, userGender;
static int userAge;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I guess I had my syntax and logic mixed up. Thank you again for the quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that at the time you call this constructor:

```
Data_Storage user = new Data_Storage(userFirst, userLast, userGender, userAge);
```

You have not set values to any of the variables being passed in. Instead, you can move this line after you've collected the info from the user.

You could also shorten the code some by creating the class using the default constructor and then setting the properties directly:

```
Data_Storage user = new Data_Storage();

Console.WriteLine("Please input First Name: ");
user.firstName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please input Last Name: ");
user.lastName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please input Gender: ");
user.gender = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please input Age: ");
user.age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(user);
```